# Yii::app()->session не работает с массивами

Tags: php, yii

```
Yii::app()->session['report'] = array();
Yii::app()->session['report'][0] = 'Hello world';
```

Выдает ошибку: **Indirect modification of overloaded element of CHttpSession has no effect**

Два часа убил чтобы разобраться. Все никак не хотел верить в это. Но увы...(((
То же самое с setState. Если использовать обычный $_SESSION[], то все работает как у людей.
Что скажите по этому поводу? У вас тоже не работает?

Не отвечайте пока не проверите.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте так

```
$array[0] = 'Hello World';
Yii::app()->session->add("arrayName", $array);
```